# Center in Canvas an scaled Bitmap inside public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)

Tags: java, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas

i managed to scale a bitmap.

```
Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, icon.getWidth() - 1, icon.getHeight() - 1);
Rect dest = new Rect(0,0,Math.round(newWidth), Math.round(newHeight));
canvas.drawBitmap(icon, src, dest, null);
```

The problem is that the image appears left-side of the canvas.
I want it to be in the middle of the canvas.
A big problem is that i am worried about the memory management.So i don't want to pre-create a scaled bitmap, i would prefer to use the method that creates and draws the scaled bitmap on the fly:

```
  canvas.drawBitmap(icon, src, dest, null);
```

How can I perform that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to be centered on the `Canvas`, it is simple just calculate the center coordinate and apply it on `dest`.

```
int cx = (getWidth() - newWidth) / 2;
int cy = (getHeight() - newHeight) / 2;

Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth() - 1, myBitmap.getHeight() - 1);
Rect dest = new Rect(cx, cy, cx+Math.round(newWidth), cy+Math.round(newHeight));
canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, src, dest, null);
```

However, this is not the right way to do so because you are creating 2 `Rect` every time `onDraw(Canvas)` is called. Which stays in memory as long as gc garbage collects it.

To avoid this you can precompute both `Rect` and store them as they are not as heavy as Bitmap on memory.

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: Thanks for the compliment.